# How to save game on Android SDL2 in a file best way?

Tags: android, sdl-2

I developing a crosplatform game on android and I use sdl2. How i can save game in a best way. I try something like this:

```
savefile = SDL_RWFromFile( "data/save.bin", "wb" );
```

On PC it works fine, but on android file doesn't creates. What is the easest(or the best:-)) way to save game in file on android or maybe crosplatform way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [SDL_GetPrefPath](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetPrefPath) that will give you a path that you can safely write files to across platforms, my guess is there's some permissions issue with trying to open the file there on Android.